# android seekbar custom drawable

Tags: android, android-custom-view, seekbar

I want to have a seek bar that I can show range of acceptable values like below. I know the method of setting a custom drawable to seek bar. My question is how I can build this kind of drawable with partial green part in xml.Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this Drawable, call it with SeekBar.setProgressDrawable()

```
public class PartialDrawable extends Drawable {
    private float mStart;
    private float mEnd;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public PartialDrawable(float start, float end) {
        mStart = start;
        mEnd = end;
        mPaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect b = getBounds();
        mPaint.setColor(0xff888888);
        canvas.drawRect(b,mPaint);
        mPaint.setColor(0xff00aa00);
        canvas.drawRect(b.width() * mStart, b.top, b.width() * mEnd, b.bottom, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the standard SeekBar provides a minimum and a maximum "acceptable" values.
What you can do is to simply add a background, using the method

```
mySeekBar.setProgressDrawable(Drawable d);
```

And build an image with grey and green that will be stretched.

Comment: could you please post a xml code for "grey and green" drawable. Thanks